# How to turn a variable content constant for use it as the size of std::array?

Tags: c++, class, stdarray

I have a size variable that belongs to the class. I would like to use it as the size of a std::array, but I was not able to do this. I found some articles that mention constexpr, but nothing useful so far. Can you help me?

```
#include<array>
#include<iostream>

class MyClass{
private:
        int size; //variable I need to copy the content and make it constant.
        void calculateSize(int x){
                size = 2 * x;
        }

public:
        MyClass(){}

        void createArray(int val){

                calculateSize(val);
                std::cout << "the size is: " << size << std::endl;
                std::array<int, size> myArray; // error
        }
};

int main(){

        MyClass c;
        c.createArray(5);
        return 0;
}
```

The error:

> main.cpp: In member function ‘void MyClass::createArray(int)’:
>   main.cpp:20:19: error: use of ‘this’ in a constant expression
>      std::array myArray;

Comment: This is what `std::vector` is for. Why aren't you using `std::vector` for this?

Comment: The std::vector would be a good idea, but I would like to use other containers as well. In this case, I already know in advance what size container before declaring it.

Comment: As for the error, even though you don't explicitly use `this` anywhere, it is being implicitly used when accessing member variables: `array< int, this->size >`

Comment: There are reasons you have many different containers available. They do not exist just to use different names. Each one of them has its own specific advantages and situation that they're best suited for, while they would not be optimal in other situations. In this situation, a `std::array` is not the right fit, or choice, but a `std::vector` is. That's what it's for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem here is a misunderstanding of what constant means. In C++, std::array's must be of constant size, where constant means "the size is known at compile-time." As your class suggests, the `size` variable is calculated at runtime. Likewise, the `constexpr` keyword can only be used for a variable whose value is known at compile time and will not ever change.

So you have a couple options.

1. You can use a `std::vector` and initialize it with a size

   ```cpp
   std::vector<int> vec(5); // Initializes a vector of size 5
   ```
2. If you really do know the size of the array at compile time, you can use constexpr

   ```cpp
   constexpr int size = 2 * 10;
   std::array<int, size> arr; // Make an array of size 20
   ```

Comment: I'm considering your point. Maybe the std::vector::reserve() can be useful too since I know the size of the vector.

Comment: Passing 5 to the constructor of `std::vector` behaves closer to what you asked for. However, if you don't want default constructed elements in your vector, then calling reserve and pushing elements might be a better approach, indeed.

Answer (score 2):

This is simply not possible. Non-static member variables are not compile time constant values. Template arguments must be compile time constants. Therefore you cannot use a non-static member variable as a size of a `std::array`.

If you want to have an array with a size determined at runtime, then you need to allocate the array dynamically. The simplest way to achieve that is to use a `std::vector`.

If you want to have a constant sized array, then you can use a compile time constant for that purpose. Such value cannot be a non-static member variable.

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative solution, using templates:

```
template <int _size>
class MyClass{
private:
    // size calculation at compile time
    constexpr static int size = _size * 2; 

public:
    // parameter removed since it's unnecessary
    void createArray(){  
        std::cout << "the size is: " << size << std::endl;
        std::array<int, size> myArray;
    }
};

int main(){
    // pass size as template argument
    MyClass<5> c;
    c.createArray();
    return 0;
}
```